Symfony 7.1 Security Bundle : CheckCredentials in AbstractLoginFormAuthenticator
I try to implement a custom "checkCredentials" for the AbstractLoginFormAuthenticator but as mentioned here #40869, it is no longer in this class.
GitHubGitHub
AbstractGuardAuthenticator not implementing the right interface (AuthenticatorInterface) causing AuthenticatorManager::executeAuthenticator() to throw an error ?! · Issue #40869 · symfony/symfony
Reason
If I want to use "checkCredentials" it is because I migrate a symfony 3.3 project to 7.1
In my project (3.3), password are hashed with sha512 + base64 + salt.
I also tried this, but it does not work.
For info,

to get base64 sha512 hashed password => $user->getPassword()
to get salt => $user->getSalt()


I've done more symfony migrations than I can count, so I would advise you to look up the latest documentation about security/authentication and implement it. In itself it's usually pretty simple with very few classes so it would be easier to do it like this, even if you have a more complex logic behind your authentication. Even if your legacy password use an old encryption system you can still use it or provide your own password hasher, and progressively move your password to a newer/safer encryption using password migrations

I did check symfony 7 documentation.
I found solution for registration with password hashing, but nothing for the LoginForm :(

I finally found the solution with the CustomCredentials in the CustomAuthenticator
